# How can scroll position keep on active item in sidebar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I tried many way in stackoverflow and jquery examples, but I could not run it in my grav theme. When I click a item on my sidebar, page refreshes and sidebar scroll position goes to top. I want scroll position stay in last clicked item.

In more detail,

Theme files consists of two main pages; base.html.twig and sidebar.html.twig. It a kind of documentation theme. Menu in sidebar.html.twig and content in base.html.twig. When I change scroll position in content and refresh page, scroll position stays what i read but long menu in sidebar could not stay on active item.

I think, it can be possible 2 solition way. Ajax menu maybe a solution or a jquery script for keep position of scroll.

Comment: I found an example [robust theme](https://pixinvent.com/bootstrap-admin-template/robust/html/ltr/vertical-menu-template/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    console.log("scrolled --------------------------")
    sidemenuitemintoview()
  }, 100);
});

var sidemenuitemintoview = function() {
  var a, b, i = 0;
  a = document.getElementById("sidebar")
  console.log("sidemenuitemintoview()")
  if (!a || !a.getElementsByClassName) {return false;}
  b = a.getElementsByClassName("active");
  if (b.length < 1) {return false;}  
  while (!isIntoView(a, b[0])) {
    i++
    if (i > 1000) {break;}
    a.scrollTop += 10;
  }
}
function isIntoView(x, y) {
  var a = x.scrollTop;
  var b = a + window.innerHeight;
  var ytop = y.offsetTop;
  var ybottom = ytop + 140;
  return ((ybottom <= b) && (ytop >= a));
}
```